# how to deploy django with nginx,guniorn and postgresql

Tags: django, windows, nginx, gunicorn

Can anyone please give reference document for deployment process django with nginx gunicorn and postgresql on windows machine

Can anyone please give reference document for deployment process django with nginx gunicorn and postgresql on windows machine

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial in DigitalOcean titled **How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 22.04**. You can follow that document.

To check [click here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04)